# Server side only manual login flow to facebook in a canvas app with asp.net identity web api external logins

Tags: android, asp.net, angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am following this tutorial http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/.

The first step to facebook login flow is to click a facebook login button which links to this url:

`http://ngauthenticationapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Facebook&response_type=token&client_id=ngAuthApp& redirect_uri=http:/\
/ngauthenticationweb.azurewebsites.net/authcomplete.html`

In my case I am using a facebook canvas app, that is embedded inside facebook. So I don't have a login button. Instead what should I display/do
in my index.html that initiates login flow within facebook application.

I am not using Facebook SDK. I will do this server side only, I've setup everything following the tutorial, but I don't know if that is usable withi\
n a canvas app.

Facebook docs says in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.4:

> Your app must initiate a redirect to an endpoint which will display the login dialog

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={app-id}&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}`

So in my case should I redirect users to that url above that is linked by a facebook login button, would that be ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a detailed [login on Facebook doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas/login). To quote some important parts of it here:

> Because your game is loaded in an iframe, returning a 302 to redirect
>   the user to the Login Dialog will be unsuccessful. Instead you must
>   target the top (or _top) frame for redirect, which causes the parent
>   window to redirect to the Login Dialog URL.

And also:

> When using the non-JavaScript SDK redirect method, they will be sent
>   back to the redirect_uri passed to the Login Dialog. In this case, we
>   recommend you set this redirect_uri to be the Canvas URL of your game.
>   Because the signed_request will be POSTed along with an access token
>   this time, your app can now capture the token from the signed request
>   as above.